# How to configure subdomains for Apache2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache, configuration, dns, subdomain, virtualhost

I followed these [instructions to configure subdomains for apache](http://wp.headynation.com/localhost-subdomains-on-ubuntu-linux-10-10-maverick/). I can access the subdomain using `http://localhost/test` though I cannot access it via `http://test.localhost`. How can I realize the latter?

```
# /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.localhost
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Server name
    ServerName test.localhost

    # Document root
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test/

    # Custom log file locations
    ErrorLog  /var/www/test/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/test/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When you followed the description, it should work. So what did you miss?

Comment: Did you add `test.localhost` to your hosts file to make sure it resolves to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @Marc B - Thank you! I configured the subdomain to 127.0.0.2 as described in the tutorial. Now it works! Pls let me grant you the answer flag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As **Mark B** already answered correctly the problem was a misconfiguration in `/etc/hosts`. The correct configuration is:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1     test.localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

The blog post you linked to (from my blog) instructs to set up a new VirtualHost element with an ip of 127.0.0.2 so you can create multiple subdomains easily.

You're setup using 127.0.0.1 will work great for one subdomain, but if you plan on adding more, I'd suggest setting up the new VirtualHost elements as described in the post.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring subdomain is very easy when working with apache tomcat 7 and ubuntu server.

http://javatute.com/javatute/faces/post/tomcat/2014/configuring-subdomain-in-server.xml.xhtml

Actually subdomain takes time to configure as we add it using cPanel at least 2-3 days and then configuring server.xml and restarting tomcat we can run it as expected.